# Reducing Code Size that Prints a Shape

Tags: java

Code to print in below format? I have a code but I feel lot of unnecessary 4 for loop can I reproduce the output with lesser for loop.

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

My Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for(int j=1; j<=3; j++) {
        for(int i=3; i>=j; i--) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its gud,u can move with this

Comment: Does it do what it is supposed to do? If so, and to my eyes it is not "too big", then you should be fine with it the way it is. However, a question like this might be better served on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, I believe.

Comment: There's ways to reduce this code, but compact code isn't necessarily good code. As Niks said, just move on. This is fine.

Comment: your code is not too big.  do you have any other questions?

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, I thought there will be way to reduce number of for loop or any other best code.

Comment: Take a look at the graph of the "abs()" function. You could make use of that here to condense things.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same in a single line of code (plus the class and `main` boilerplate):

```
System.out.println("*\n**\n***\n****\n***\n**\n*");
```

Comment: +0, because it does not contain an algorithm to print triangles of arbitrary length

Comment: Which solution is best is going to depend on what *other* constraints you're operating under. Ask your teacher.

Comment: @Sam Neither does OPs -he is using constants in his loops

Comment: @SamIam, that wasn't in the requirements as stated. Asking the right question is part of the learning process.

Comment: Okay, You guys have managed to hit on one of my pet peeves. it's -1 now for pedantically following the letter of the question and not considering what the OP might really need

Answer (score 2):

You could break the logic up into a method that gets `n` stars like so,

```
// Build a String of n stars.
public static String getStars(int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append("*");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And then call it with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int MAX = 4;
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
        System.out.println(getStars(i));
    }
    for (int i = MAX - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(getStars(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the lulz...
(fill generates a String of chars)

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
final int size = 3;
list.add(fill('*', size));
for(int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
   list.addFirst(fill('*', i));
   list.addLast(fill('*', i));
 }

 for(String elem : list)
   System.out.println(elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about some nice recursion?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    doRecursion(1);
}

public static void printSomeStars(int count)
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void doRecursion(int count)
{
    printSomeStars(count);

    if (count <= 4)
    {
        doRecursion(count+1);
    }

    printSomeStars(count-1);
}
```